# Loose typing option for Json.NET similar to GSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, gson

In GSON, you can deserialize into a JsonObject, which in turns allows you to access JsonElements and call methods such as getAsString(), getAsInt(), etc...

This is incredibly useful for my use case: I am serializing data with JSON and sending it over a network. Data is sent along with protocol identifiers which tells the client how to process the data. I do not want to create a class for every different sort of protocol, so deserializing as a JsonObject allows me a lot of flexibility.

I can't find an analogous way to do this in C#. I figure I need to roll my own JsonElement/Object/Array/Primitive hierarchy, but I don't really know where to begin. Is that even the best way to do it?

I want to:

Deserialize json in C# into a structure which lets me access data as specific types, without using a class "skeleton" for the data.

EDIT:

I am restricted to .NET 3.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Those solutions would work great, but I am restricted to .NET 3.5. So, no dynamics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) can do this--you don't need to deserialize into a class:

```
int value = JObject.Parse(myJsonString)["property"]["subProperty"].Value<int>();
```

See the documentation for [LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for more information.